# What is a $\{2,3\}$-group?

Tags: group-theory, terminology, definition, symmetric-groups

I found the following statement in Cameron's *Projective and Polar Spaces* (page 120 [here](https://webspace.maths.qmul.ac.uk/p.j.cameron/pps/pps8.pdf)):

If two such automorphisms of order $3$ have a common fixed line, then they generate a $\{2,3\}$-group, since the stabiliser of a line in $GL(4,2)$ is a $\{2,3\}$-group.

What does $\{2,3\}$-group mean here? It doesn't seem to be defined anywhere else in the book, and I was unable to find a definition online. The discussion is related to alternating groups, if that helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means a finite group such that the only primes dividing its order are $2$ and $3$.

Comment: Just to confirm: is it that $2$ and $3$ must both divide the order, or is it just that no other prime can divide the order? I ask because it helps me make sense of a statement in the next paragraph.

Comment: The latter: no other prime can divide the order.